# How can I find the value of a cell that is a section of a datagridview specified row and column?

Tags: c#, search, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewrow

**How do I find the section of a specified column and row?**

I am having a datagridview as a table,as you can see in the picture below.

[image]

In the datagridview, the cells are containing rules. (TE',1) means it is the rule TE', and it is the 1st rule.

My task is like I have an expression, such as i+i*i, and using "rules" as showed in the first columns, I find the value of the cell in the datagridview, which's column is the first character of the expression, and which's row is the first character of the second part. I know it sounds nonsense at first, but **let me clear this with an example.**

The first step is (i+i*i#,E#,empty). I check the first character of the first part, its **i**, I check the first character of the second part, its **E**, I look for the section of column **i** and row **E**.
It is **(TE',1)**, so in the starting step, I replace **E** for the cell value **TE'**, and add the number **1** for the third part, which was empty at the beginning. Now the actual "formula" is like:

(i+i*i#,TE',1)

I replaced the second part with the "rule" I found at the cell, and added the number of the rule to the third part of the formula.

Next step, I find the section of column **i** and row **T**, it is **(FT',4)**, so I replace **T** with **FT'**, and add the number 4 to the third part.

(i+i*i#, FT'E'#,14)

Now I Look for the section of column **i** and row **F** , its **(i,8)**. I do the replace again.

(i+i*i#,iT'E'#,148)

Now for column **i** and row **i** its a pop, so i remove both from the formula.

(+i*i#,T'E'#,148)

Now I look for the column **+** and row **T'**.......

The whole procedure ends when there are only **#** and numbers in the formula, like (#,#,1942682).

I filled the datagridview like this (*I am also very sorry about this ..*):

```
private void AddRows()
    {
        string[] header_Row = new string[] { "", "+", "*", "(", ")", "i", "#", };
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(header_Row);

        string[] E_Row = new string[] { "E", "", "", "(TÉ,1)", "", "(TÉ,1)", "" };
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(E_Row);

        string[] EComma_Row = new string[] { "É", "(+TÉ,2)", "", "", "(Eps,3)", "", "(Eps,3)" };
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(EComma_Row);

        string[] T_Row = new string[] { "T", "", "", "(FT',4)", "", "(FT',4)", "" };
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(T_Row);

        string[] TComma_Row = new string[] { "T'", "(Eps,6)", "(+FT',5)", "", "(Eps,6)", "", "(Eps,6)" };
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(TComma_Row);

        string[] F_Row = new string[] { "F", "", "", "(E,7)", "", "(i,8)", "" };
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(F_Row);

        string[] emptyRow = new string[] { };
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(emptyRow);

        string[] Plus_Row = new string[] { "+", "pop", "", "", "", "", "" };
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(Plus_Row);

        string[] Star_Row = new string[] { "*", "", "pop", "", "", "", "" };
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(Star_Row);

        string[] StartingBracket_Row = new string[] { "(", "", "", "pop", "", "", "" };
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(StartingBracket_Row);

        string[] EndingBracket_Row = new string[] { ")", "", "", "", "pop", "", "" };
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(EndingBracket_Row);

        string[] i_Row = new string[] { "i", "", "", "", "", "pop", "" };
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(i_Row);

        string[] Hashmark_Row = new string[] { "#", "", "", "", "", "", "Elfogad" };
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(Hashmark_Row);
    }
```

So the problem is that if I have the first formula (i+i*i#,E#,empty), how do I search for the **i** column's and **E** row's section in the datagridview, to get the value of that cell?

Comment: It is unclear what your question is. To reference an individual cell in the grid may look something like… `datagridview.Rows[Target_Row_Index}.Cells[Target_Column_Index].Value`  Obviously you will want to check the `Target_Row_Index` and `Target_Column_Index` to make sure they are within the bounds of the number of rows and columns.

Comment: Okay, let me clear this. How do I find the cell that is in the section of column **i** and row **E**? I want to get the value of that cell.

Comment: Hmmm…. From your picture and code, I am guessing the grid does not have a “Header” (row with column names), therefore, since E is in what appears to be row one (1) and `i` is column five (5). Therefore the intersection would be `datagridview.Rows[1}.Cells[5].Value`

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to attempt to follow the logic of what your program is doing, but to get to the values of each cell  I put together the following example:

This will populate two rows of a grid. When the button is clicked it will loop through the rows and columns of the datagridview and display a message with the indexes and the value of the cell.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    string[] row1 = new string[] { "A1", "A2", "A3" };
    string[] row2 = new string[] { "B1", "B2", "B3" };

    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row1);
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row2);
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            string s = string.Format("I am at row {0} , col{1} the value is {2}", row.Index, col.Index, (string)dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[col.Index].Value);
            MessageBox.Show(s);
         }
    }
}
```

The Value of a cell, when accessed will be an object. That is why I have a string cast on the line within the loop. You just need to know the row index and column index. The first column and row start at 0.

Comment: Hey Tim, thank you for your answer, it is helpful. I am now wondering, is there a way to only loop through the first row of the DataGridView?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through the first row only, just use 0 as the index.
foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
         string cellValue = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[col.Index].Value)

You could actually write a method, something like what is shown below, it would return a null if you passed in an invalid row or col, otherwise it would return a string value of the cell content. This is assuming all of you data will be strings.

You would then just call it:

```
  string s = GetCellValue(row, col);


   string GetCellValue(int row, int col)
   {

   try
    {
      return (string)dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Rather than posting two answers on the same question, [edit your first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59023060/edit) to include the updated information of this one.